# Intercepting or wrapping log4j root logger or appender

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I would like to inject a piece of information into all messages logged by anything, including third-party code.  The reason is that, in our web-services-oriented application, requests come in with unique IDs and I want those unique IDs to be attached to all log messages that occur while processing a request, to assist in later analysis.  I am already tracking the "current request" using ThreadLocal<> techniques, so I have the ability to fetch the "current request" from anywhere.

To that end, I would like to configure log4j such that I can inject the requestID into messages before they reach the root logger (or appender?).  I know that I can just make a whole new Appender that implements append() and does whatever it wants with the output, but that's not what I'm asking for.  I want output to ultimately go to whatever appender is configured at startup, but with the additional information attached.

I am using log4j 1.x, but if a move to log4j 2.x or using slf4j makes this significantly easier, I would consider it.